# How to post a formdata by @resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, form-data

This is a question when i post the formdata by using "@resource" in angular.I got a status of "500".I don't konw where is the mistake.Tell me why please?==
the code:

```
return $resource(baseURL+'/finance/validate/withdraw',{
    save:{
      method:'POST',
      params:{
        cvsFile:'@cvsFile',
        username:'@username',
        alipayAccount:'@alipayAccount'
      },
      transformRequest:angular.identity,
      headers:{'Content-Type':undefined}
    }
```

code and status images as followings:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return $resource(baseURL+'/finance/validate/withdraw',{
    save:{
      method:'POST',
      params:$.param({
        cvsFile:'@cvsFile',
        username:'@username',
        alipayAccount:'@alipayAccount'
      }),
      transformRequest:angular.identity,
      headers:{ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }
```